# VSCode not stopping at breakpoints when test launched using npm and package.json scripts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

From within **VSCode** I would like to launch the current file (e.g. **my-function.spec.ts**) and do interactive debugging setting breakpoints.

For the test to run I need to set some environment variables, e.g. `MONGO=mongodb://localhost:27017/`.  For this reason I launch the test via an **npm script** and pass the environment variables using the `"envFile"` property of the configurations defined in **launch.json**.

**launch.json** is

```
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Current TS Tests File",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "test-one"]
        },
    ]
}
```

the **package.json** script is

```
"scripts": {
   "test-one": "npm mocha -r ts-node/register",
}
```

With this configuration I am able to launch the test. The test executes as expected, but the code does not stop execution at the breakpoints I set. Any suggestion on how to make breakpoints work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration works on my machine. The source code is [in this GitHub repository.](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-vscode-nodets-debugger) Running the **Launch via NPM** configuration from the debugger hits the breakpoint on `assert`.

There are more details about debugging with `node-ts` and VS Code [in this `node-ts` issue](http://There%20are%20some%20details%20here:%20https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/46#issuecomment-277672474). Let me know if you need more help mapping this setup to your requirements.

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register --inspect --debug-brk index.test.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.12",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "test"],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

index.test.ts

```
import assert from 'assert';

describe('index', function () {
    it('should pass', function () {
        assert.equal(true, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. ` --inspect --debug-brk ` did the trick for me. Thanks